# Is there any way to modify the shutdown options for Windows 7 on the login/lock screen red button

Tags: windows, macos, boot-camp

I want to add an option on my Boot Camp enabled iMacs to add 'Restart in OSX' (using the command line shortcut) to the Red Shutdown button that appears in the right corner of the Logon screen and Lock screen for Windows 7.

I can normally login to each workstation and click 'Restart in OSX' on the Boot Camp icon but I want to be able to restart into my OSX environment in a lab of 32 computers without taking the extra step of logging in to each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way, but it's not easy. :)

Since the login screen is intended to be a secure environment, it's not something you can easily hack up (beyond basic visual changes like background images).

In Vista+ you can replace this login system with a [Custom Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx), which you will have to program (in a native code language like C++).

Also check out these questions on StackOverflow: [Adding command button to Windows Logon screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186900/adding-command-button-to-windows-logon-screen) and [Windows Login Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378549/windows-login-integration).

Comment: You said the SuperUser dirty words: to program!!

Comment: @surfasb Yeah, it's weird how sometimes you need to program a computer to have it do what you want. ;)